# Is it possible for me to install django-cors-headers version 1.1.0? If so, how?

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

When I try to install django-cors-headers v1.1.0 on Django 1.7, I'm getting the pip error "No matching distribution found for django-cors-headers-1.1.0"

Is it possible for me to install version 1.1.0? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a specific package number by doing 
`pip install package==X.X` where X.X is the version number.

So in your case, you just need to do `pip install django-cors-headers==1.1.0`.

That said, the oldest supported Django version is 1.8 according to their [documentation](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers).